# LNK2019 - Link to external unsolved symbol

Tags: c++

I try to load a image with **D3DXCreateTextureFromFile**. D3DXCreateTextureFromFile is located in the **D3dx9.lib**. So I included the lib like:
http://s21.postimg.org/3ujn9o9g7/Includes.png

I also added the lib in the linker
http://s10.postimg.org/rqida3ie1/linker.png

I also set the external lib paths, at "Include paths" and "Libfolder"

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x64   and
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include

I set the configuration type to "MFC in a static lib" and the character set to "Unicode". But I still get the error:

```
Fehler  5   error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_D3DXCreateTextureFromFileW@12" in Funktion ""public: __thiscall Image::Image(char *,struct IDirect3DDevice9 *)" (??0Image@@QAE@PADPAUIDirect3DDevice9@@@Z)".
```

If I translate it into english

```
Fehler  5   error LNK2019: Link to a external unsolved symbol"_D3DXCreateTextureFromFileW@12" in function""public: __thiscall Image::Image(char *,struct IDirect3DDevice9 *)" (??0Image@@QAE@PADPAUIDirect3DDevice9@@@Z)".
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also get the error: Fehler 3 error LNK2019: Link to an external unsolved symbol "_Direct3DCreate9@4", since I added the external lib

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Your screen shot might vanish when your interest in the question is shutdown. Please include the information in the question at Stackoverflow. So it might help others to read the question if they have similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I linked to following path

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x64
- instead of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86

After changing to the 32bit libs, it worked.